# How to enable Swagger entity controllers using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am building a personal project using Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.2.

I use this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have one entity

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="transaction")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 20)
    @UuidGenerator(style = UuidGenerator.Style.AUTO)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;
    @Column(name="type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TypeEnum type;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="transaction_date")
    private Date transactionDate;
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userId;

}
```

With this JpaRepository

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, String> {

    Transaction getCreditsByDescription(String description);

    @Query("select t from Transaction t")
    List<Transaction> findAllTransaction();

    List<Transaction> findAllTransactionByType(TypeEnum type);
}
```

The transaction-entity-controller is not showing in Swagger. Only the defined controller is showing in my application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D3hd.png)

I tried using other open dependency, this doesn't work

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't see any REST controller...

Answer (score 0):

latest version of Swagger specification, now known as OpenAPI 3.0, is better supported by the Springdoc project and should be used for documenting Spring REST API: Follow documentation:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by adding this:

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.4</version>
  </dependency>


I found the solution using the documentation found in this https://springdoc.org/